# When second gear is engaged the car doesnt accelerate and engine doesnt rev up? audi a3 1.6 2005

Tags: transmission, clutch, acceleration, lean

I recently had a gearbox which went through the casing and needed to be refurbished. Had a new clutch replaced along with it. Once i picked the car up i began noticing that when the car goes into 2nd gear the car throttle will not accelerate the car and the engine will not rev even when i press it. This would only happen in second gear(this seems to also be very random and not a constantly occurrence)  and to get the car accelerating again i have a choice of either pressing on the clutch pedal (whilst its engaged in 2nd gear) and the car will suddenly regain power or change into any other gear. I have before accelerated up to 5k revs on second gear and around 4-5k the acceleration would completely disengage and i'd have to change gears.

I went back under warranty to the mechanics and they took the car into Volkswagen specialist which came out with codes that the car is running lean (I have cat back exhaust, k&n filter) however this problem wasnt occouring before the broken gearbox and even during commute with the broken gearbox to the mechanics. Any help is much appreciated as i need to start narrowing possible causes for this, mechanical or electrical

Comment: Does the instrument panel show which gear you currently have selected?

Comment: No it’s a manual car

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that the engine ECU normally knows which gear is selected so that it can use that information when controlling power output.  Maybe the sensor that supplies the gear information is sometimes malfunctioning for 2nd gear, so the ECU limits power output.  Changing gear will then give the ECU valid data again.  It could be that operating the clutch nudges the sensor to start working again while in 2nd gear.

Comment: This does sound like a very reasonable suggestion but wouldn’t this give a engine warning light ?

Comment: Don't know, but you clearly have a fault that isn't illuminating the warning light.

Comment: I would have a look underneath to check if there are wires coming from the gearbox.  If you can find a wiring diagram, you could post it for us to check.

Comment: I’m gonna have the gearbox and clutch opened up again and checked by my mechanic, he however has no idea why this only happens in second gear and no other gear

Comment: If you find out what is wrong, make sure you add the answer here.